# No impact of payload on scrappy request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am facing strange issue.

```
url = ["https://nr.aws-achat.info/_extranet/index.cfm?fuseaction=mEnt.lister"]

payload = {
            'rechInputCPV':'03000000-1',
            'rechInputMetier':'',
            'texte':'',
            'btnSub':'Afficher'
           
        }

yield scrapy.Request(url[0],method='POST',body=json.dumps(payload),callback=self.parse)
```

in above case of scrappy request,  the response is same as if I pass payload as blank dict.

Expectation : if pass rechInputCPV':'03000000- I should get 60 rows of data .

I have implemented the same thing using python requests module and there it works .

but in scrappy,  payload doesn't impact the response .

Note: I have cross-check authentication , there is no issue in AUTH I can see user in the received page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following issues resolved by using `Scrapy.FormRequest` instead of `Scrapy.Request`.